# Discord.net GetMessagesAsync() is returning null

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have been trying to make my Discord BOT **fetch a list of X number of messages** in a specific Discord Channel. But all methods I have tried so far have ended up returning null to the local variable created to store said list.

I asked the "Discord.net" Discord group for help but nobody there could help me with my issue.

My code goes as follows:

```
public async Task OnDeleteDiscordMessage()
    {
        IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await discordSocketClient.GetGuild(guildID).GetTextChannel(channelID).GetMessagesAsync(10).Flatten();

        foreach (IMessage message in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

The console returns nothing, with the use of a breakpoint I was able to notice the variable "message" returns null.

Comment: Try switching to the Beta Branch Disocrd 1.x is pretty buggy sometimes.

Comment: Also at which point of time are you calling this method

Comment: @Twenty A separate class handles commands such as this Task. It will receive the command and and await this task. It’s also a simple asynchronous Task.

Comment: @Twenty how would I go about doing this? I got mine through Visual Studio itself

Comment: When you add this to your source `https://www.myget.org/F/discord-net/api/v3/index.json` for nuget you can get the latest beta's (which are mostly stable)

Comment: @Twenty I did it, but unfortunately I am still getting the same issue

Comment: Then it must be your Guild or Text Channel that is null. Or you are calling this method before the bot fired the ready event.

Comment: @Twenty Well, you’re not completely wrong ... I found out what the issue was, I didn’t pay much attention to the way I was handling my classes and its references when coding this particular class, so I ended up creating a new instance of the Main class whenever this code ran. I made use of static methods to fix the issue.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

```
public async Task OnDeleteDiscordMessage()
        {
            var messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(10).FlattenAsync();
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Content);
            }
        }
```

You first store the 10 last messages of a channel in a variable and then you loop through each message and do something, in your case you write a console line. One last thing, in order to get the text of a message we use `message.Content`. You can call this function by a command or you can even make it a command, if I understood correctly what you are asking.